# Suppose $g\circ f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous. Is $g\mid_{f(X)}$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification

Let $X,Y$ and $Z$ be topological spaces. Let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ such that $f$ is one-to-one. Suppose $g\circ f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous. Can we conclude that $g\mid_{f(X)}$ is continuous? If not under what conditions does it hold?

My attempt:

We know that $g=(g\circ f)\circ f^{-1}$ and the domain of $f^{-1}$ is $f(X)$. Since $g\circ f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous, then $g$ is continuous on $f(X)$.

I'm not sure if I missed some technicalities on the domains/codomains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, although let me formalize it better. To be more precise, consider $f':X\to f(X)$, $f'(x)=f(x)$, which is a bijection (since $f$ is injective). What you say is that $f'^{-1}$ is continuous.

Next if $g\circ f$ is continuous then so is $g_{|f(X)}\circ f'$ because these are literally equal functions.

Finally $g_{|f(X)}=(g_{|f(X)}\circ f')\circ f'^{-1}$, and thus it is continuous as well.